# Primefaces 4.0 p:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, valuechangelistener

i am using Primefaces4.0 with JSF2.0
i want to render `valueChangeListener` on `p:SelectOneMenu`
so far:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{removeAgent.groupNumber}" effect="drop" valueChangeListener="#{removeAgent.valueChange}" onchange="submit()"> 
        <f:selectItems id="resGrp" value="#{removeAgent.allGroups}" var="grp" itemLabel="#{grp.groupName}" itemValue="#{grp.id}"/>  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

it works fine in this piece of code but i want it in primefaces

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{removeAgent.groupNumber}" effect="drop" valueChangeListener="#{removeAgent.valueChange}" onchange="submit()"> 
        <f:selectItems id="resGrp" value="#{removeAgent.allGroups}" var="grp" itemLabel="#{grp.groupName}" itemValue="#{grp.id}"/>  
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is the problem? What does not work?

Comment: `valueChangeListener` even i am also make page `submit()` but for `<h:SelectOneMenu>` it works fine, my whole app is in PF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In primefaces you can use code like below :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{removeAgent.groupNumber}" effect="drop"> 
    <f:selectItems id="resGrp" value="#{removeAgent.allGroups}" var="grp" itemLabel="#{grp.groupName}" itemValue="#{grp.id}"/>
    <p:ajax update="nextElementID" listener="#{removeAgent.valueChange}" oncomplete="submit()" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

update attribute of ajax tag is DOM element that should be updated after the ajax request. It's very useful if you have select form like city/province and so on. If you don't need, you can leave it out.